# Rust: Simplify generic type declaration

Tags: generics, rust

I have something like the following:

```
trait SubContainer<T> {}
struct Container<T, S: SubContainer<T>> {}

struct SubContainerImpl {}
impl SubContainer<u8> for SubContainerImpl {}

fn main() {
  let c = Container<u8, SubContainerImpl> {}; // actual usage
  // how I want to use it:
  // let c = Container<SubContainerImpl> {};
}
```

Help me rework the Container struct to get rid of the T param!

Comment: You cannot get rid of the `T` type parameter on `Container` unless you choose to make `SubContainer` use an associated type rather than a generic type parameter. For instance, if `SubContainerImpl` also implemented `SubContainer<u16>`, the hypothetical type `Container<SubContainerImpl>` would have two choices for `T`: `u8` and `u16`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `u8` with `_`:

```rs
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait SubContainer<T> {}
struct Container<T, S: SubContainer<T>> {
    PhantomData: PhantomData<(T, S)>,
}

struct SubContainerImpl {}
impl SubContainer<u8> for SubContainerImpl {}

fn main() {
  let c = Container::<_, SubContainerImpl> { PhantomData }; // actual usage
  // how I want to use it:
  // let c = Container<SubContainerImpl> {};
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2938c78854d0366f17b0d708c58a9e67